# Passwordless mysql_connect

Tags: php, mysql

I have a cron job that calls a PHP script that causes the following error message.

`Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure`

I can currently connect to the database without a password prompt using `mysql --login-path=foo` after using `mysql_config_editor --login-path=foo --host=hostname --user=username --password`.

However, I can't figure out how to set `$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');` to be passwordless.

TIA

Comment: Before you go any further, you should not be using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated.  You should use either [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Connecting via a line in your PHP script with a password doesn't make an entry in the command history with your password, so it's not "insecure". What's the issue? Are you still getting a warning?

Comment: @PatrickQ, Seems that I would still have the same issue with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, yes, I'm still getting the error when a cron job calls a PHP script that has the password in the mysql_connect function.

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't waste you're time figuring out how to do it using out-dated functions. Start using the new interfaces/extensions, and then if you still have a problem, ask with the new functions.

Comment: The PHP connection line is not related to the warning: "Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure". Look elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your MySQL account has a password or not, but I'm guessing password on the command line is probably stored in your `my.cnf` file.

In PHP, you don't have to supply the password parameter to `mysql_connect', and if you leave it empty it will look at an ini setting: http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-password

I agree with @Patrick though, you should, where possible, not use mysql_* functions because they're deprecated, though I feel your pain as I currently work on a system that we can't yet upgrade.